# Dynamcially set Template name

Tags: knockout.js

How to set the KO template name dynamically when the dropn down selected value changes..

I tried this but I don't get the correct template.

```
<select data-bind="options: Attributes, optionsText: 'AttributeName', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select Attribute...',value :SelectedAttribute"></select>
<div data-bind="template: { name: SelectedAttribute }"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code what you have so far and demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `SelectedAttribute` is not null and add `()` to observable to get its value:

```
<!-- ko if: SelectedAttribute -->
<div data-bind="template: { name: SelectedAttribute() }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/HUExe/

It seems to me that `template` binding doesn't unwrap value passed to name option.